# Trouble sending a char array in one class to an observable list in another in Java

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, observablelist

I am new to Java and I am trying to send a string / array generated in one class to another to be used in an observable list. Basically I want the string in one class sent to the other class as a char array to an observable list so the letters can be presented in a tile like format in the GUI.

This is my first class:

```
public class Phrase {

    String gamePhrase = "Keep moving forwards";
    String guessPhrase = gamePhrase.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]", "*"); 

    char[] array = guessPhrase.toCharArray();

}
```

This is my second class where I Am trying to add add the characters to:

```
private ObservableList<Node> phraseList;

private Phrase p1 = new Phrase();

private void start() {

    phraseList.clear();
    for (p1.toCharArray()) {
        phraseList.add(new LetterBoxes(c));
    }
}


private static class LetterBoxes extends StackPane {
    private Rectangle bg = new Rectangle(40, 60);
    private Text text;

    public LetterBoxes(char x) {
        bg.setFill(x == ' ' ? Color.DARKSEAGREEN : Color.WHITE);
        bg.setStroke(Color.BLUE);

        text = new Text(String.valueOf(x).toUpperCase());
        text.setFont(DEFAULT_FONT);
        text.setVisible(false);

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        getChildren().addAll(bg, text);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to get the array in correctly and am having difficulty moving forward. Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (p1.toCharArray()) {
```

is wrong for 2 reasons:

1. The `Phrase` class does not provide a `toCharArray` method.
2. The syntax of the `for` loop is wrong.

you probably need a getter for the array in the `Phase` class and use a enhanced `for` loop:

```
public class Phrase {

    public char[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    ...

}
```

```
for (char c : p1.getArray()) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It was stressing me out. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are french no? Ce tombe bien, moi aussi ! 
But something are really wrong I guess like that:

```
for(p1.toCharArray())
```

I don't know what you want to do but I don't think it works.

So first, you have to pass your variable in the class "phrase" in private, and build some getters-setters:

```
public class Phrase {
private String gamePhrase = "Keep moving forwards";
private String guessPhrase = gamePhrase.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]", "*"); 
private char[] array = guessPhrase.toCharArray();

public void setGamePhrase(String s){
    gamePhrase = s;
}
public void setGuessPhrase(String s){
    guessPhrase = s;
}
public void setArray(Char[] s){
    array = s;
}
public String getGamePhrase(){
    return gamePhrase;
}
public String getGuessPhrase(){
    return guessPhrase;
}
public char[] getArray(){
    return array;
}
}
```

With that you will be able to set and get your data correctly. Then, on your other class, you can do

```
private Phrase p1 = new Phrase();
private void start() {

    phraseList.clear();
    for (int i=0; i<p1.getArray().size(); i++) { //Perhaps it's something else than .size(), but the idea is that you take the size of array
        phraseList.add(new LetterBoxes(p1.getArray().get(i))); // Here is the same thing, perhaps it's not get(i), but the idea is that you take the value which is associate to the rank i in array.
     }
}
public LetterBoxes(char x) {...}//don't change this function
```

Hope it will help you,

don't hesitate to answer me

Comment: I am not French i'm afraid.

I would just like to know if this works if the guess phrase will continually be changing. So essentially the guess phrase will be filled in from the game phrase like a wheel of fortune like game and then I need to constantly add to the GUI?

Comment: Your help really made my life easier. Thanks so much!